# How can I test if LVM works on Ubuntu Lucid?

Tags: ubuntu, testing, lvm

I got LVM2 installed on Ubuntu Lucid. I have a volume group on /dev/fluid with free space (150Gb).
I need to know if LVM is installed and working properly.

**How can I test that LVM is working properly?**

Thanks

**Edit:**

I am probably looking for a way to read/write a file in a test volume.

Here's my volume group info, in case it helps:

```
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               fluid
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        2
  Metadata Sequence No  9
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                2
  Act PV                2
  VG Size               151,09 GiB
  PE Size               4,00 MiB
  Total PE              38679
  Alloc PE / Size       4864 / 19,00 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       33815 / 132,09 GiB
```

Comment: Small comment — traditionally it’s a good idea to start your volume group with ‘vg’ to make it more obvious (and to avoid conflicts in /dev). So “vgfluid” would be a better name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I think I found how to do this, this is pretty much what I was looking for:

```
sudo lvcreate -L50M -n test fluid
sudo mkfs.ext3 /dev/fluid/test
sudo mkdir /media/test
sudo mount /dev/fluid/test /media/test/
```

And then I copied some file on it and checked the checksum.

source: http://www.nikhef.nl/~dennisvd/lvmcrap.html

Answer (score 1):

There are several commands you can use:

```
pvs - lists physical volumes
vgs - this lists the volume groups
lvs - lists logical volumes
```

What is /dev/fluid ?

**UPDATE**

What you want (I think) is to mount your logical volume.

```
ls /dev/mapper
```

Then mount:

```
mount /dev/mapper/fluid-{something-you-found-above} /mnt
```

Comment: /dev/fluid is my volume group, see edit.

Answer (score 0):

If the logical volumes are mountable and you can write files to them, it's working. You can use the commands that cstamas mentions for more info about how your volumes are set up.

Answer (score 0):

> I am probably looking for a way to read/write a file in a test volume.

Well, then just format your LV with a file system of your choice, mount it and `touch` a file on it.